# what's difference between int i=0, int i(0), int *p=new int, int *p=new int(0) in c++

Tags: c++

what's difference between

```
int i=0;
```

and

```
int i(0);

int *p=new int;
```

and

```
int *p=new int(0);
```

is `int *p=new int` is still copy initial style?

when to use `int i=0;` not `new int(0)`?

Comment: Your last question suggests you need to read about memory management in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to answer a slightly different question first.

Suppose you have a `class` or `struct` (they are pretty much the same) that looks like this:

```
struct Foo {
  int value; // Foo stores an int, called value
  Foo(int v):value(v) {}; // Foo can be constructed (created) from an int
  explicit Foo(double d):value(d) {}; // Foo can be constructed (created) from a double
  // ^^^ note that keyword.  It says that it can only be EXPLICITLY created from a double
};
```

now, this is much like an `int`, but there are a few differences.

```
Foo i = 0;
```

the above creates an `int` literal, then constructs `Foo i` with it using the `Foo(int v)` constructor.

```
Foo i(0);
```

the above creates an `int` literal, then constructs `Foo i` with it using the `Foo(int v)` constructor.  Note that I just repeated myself.

```
Foo i = Foo(0);
```

the above creates an `int` literal, then constructs `Foo i` with it using the `Foo(int v)` constructor, then copy-constructs `Foo i` from it.  However, the standard allows the compiler to "elide" (skip) the copy constructor, and instead just construct `Foo i` directly from the `int` literal `0`.

```
Foo* i = new Foo;
```

this goes to the free store (typically implemented and called the heap), gets ahold of enough memory to store a `Foo`, then default constructs it.  It then returns the address of this `Foo` object, which is then used to initialize the pointer `Foo* i`.  Now, note that the default constructor of `Foo` leaves `value` *uninitialized*.  This is a flaw in my implementation of `Foo` above (in my opinion), and except in special cases you will rarely want to do this.

Annoyingly, integer (`char`, `int`, `long`, `unsigned char`, etc), floating point (`double` or `float`) literals, and pointer literals all share this property -- by default, they are not initialized to any value.

So you should make sure they are explicitly initialized.  In the case of `Foo`, adding a line:

```
Foo():value() {}
```

is enough to do it.

```
Foo* i = new Foo(0);
```

this goes to the free store (typically implemented and called the heap), gets ahold of enough memory to store a `Foo`, then constructs it with the integer literal 0.  It then returns the address of this `Foo` object, which is then used to initialize the pointer `Foo* i`.

Now, memory in the free store generally stays reserved for your use once you ask for it until you get around to returning it, or your program shuts down.  In order to return it, you call `delete` on the same pointer, which both cases the object (`Foo` in this case) to have its destructor called (`Foo` has no destructor, so this is skipped), and then the memory is handed back to the free store to be used by a later call to `new`.

Keeping track of this is a real pain, and a source of a whole bunch of errors, so you should avoid calling `new`.  There are many ways to avoid calling `new`, including using `std::vector` to manage blocks of memory, or using `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` to create objects on the heap which manage their own lifetime via a technique known as RAII, or using `unique_ptr` when you want close control over the lifetime of a pointer (sadly, `make_unique` doesn't exist).

Now lets go further.

```
Foo i = 0.0;
```

This *fails to compile*.  I said that the constructor for `Foo(double)` is explicit, and the above only chooses to call constructors that are non-explicit.  On the other hand:

```
Foo i(0.0);
Foo i = Foo(0.0);
```

these both are willing to call explicit constructors, and work fine.

Next, C++11 brings us uniform initialization.  Instead of putting what you want to initialize something with in `()`, you put it in `{}` -- a squiggly brace.

```
Foo i{0.0};
Foo i = {0};
```

etc.  `{}` has a few differences compared to `()` based syntax -- most importantly it avoids [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problems.  Other differences include initializer list behavior, dealing with explicitly trivially constructing something (`int x()` does not construct an `int` named `x`, but `int x{}` does).

Speaking of which, time to get back to your actual question.

`int` is different than my `struct Foo` in a few ways.

First, it is not a `class` or a `struct`.  So its behavior instead of being determined by some code you write, is instead described extensively by the standard.  As it happens, C++ tries to have primitive types like `int` behave a lot like a simple user defined type like `Foo`, which is useful.

So while no "copy constructor" is called, and `int` has no constructors nor destructors at all, `int` almost exactly behaves "as if" there where such constructors.

```
int i = 0;
```

creates the integer literal 0, then initializes `int i` with it.  The compiler may elide this, and simply create the integer `int i` with the value 0 directly.  For `int`, there is no way to observe the difference directly.

```
int i(0);
```

is identical to `int i = 0`, because `int` has no non-explicit constructors.  It is just a different syntax.

Now, there is the problem of the most vexing parse.  If you typed

```
int i = int();
```

you'd get the same as `int i = 0`, but if you typed

```
int i();
```

what would happen is that the compiler would say "that could be a function named i with takes zero arguments and returns `int`", and for various annoying reasons prefers that interpretation to a default-initialized `int`.  So you get a forward-declared function named `i` instead of an integer.

As mentioned earlier, the way to avoid this is to always use this syntax:

```
int i{};
```

in C++11 compilers.

Next, we have

```
int* p = new int;
```

which creates a default constructed (uninitialized) `int` on the free store, and assigns a pointer to it to the variable `int *p`.  A copy has occurred, but it is a copy of a pointer, not the `int`.

```
int *p=new int(0);
```

is much the same, but the free store `int` created has the value 0 instead of being uninitialized.

In both these cases, you are responsible for calling `delete` once and only once on the value returned by `new`.  Failure to do so is known as a memory leak.  Using the pointer value after you have done so results in undefined behavior, and typically memory corruption.  You almost certainly won't be warned by the program that what you did is dangerous, but your program can now do utterly random things that make no sense and still be a valid C++ program.  Aligning each `new` with exactly one `delete`, and making sure that nobody uses pointers after the `delete`, and calling `delete` as early as possible, is an annoying enough program that entire categories of programming languages have been developed whose main selling feature is that they free developers from having to deal with it.

So avoid calling `new`.

Oh, and because this isn't long enough, note that my use of the "most vexing parse" above is not quite right.  The "most vexing parse" is actually:

```
int x(int());
```

rather than

```
int x();
```

because the first could be either a constructor call or a function, while the second cannot be a constructor call because the standard doesn't allow it.

However, I and most other people find the parsing rules that make `int x();`, so call it the penultimate vexing parse, and you won't be far wrong.  It still doesn't do what you would naively think it should do (create a default constructed `x`), so it is plenty vexing.

Answer (score 2):

in C and early C++ you could only use int i=0;

The `int i(0);` pattern is the same as a constructor for a general type

```
T i(0);
```

So it was added as an alternative to `int i=0;` which does not look like a general constructor pattern. This is useful when templates are used. So the template can use int as well as classes.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i=0; 
int i(0);
```

these are the same, with two different initialization syntaxes (C-like the first, constructor-style the second); in line of principle they are slightly different when dealing with classes (the first one implies a - potentially elided - call to a copy constructor, the second doesn't), but for `int`s they are effectively the same.

```
int *p=new int; 
int *p=new int(0);
```

In the first one the `int` is not initialized (it will have whatever value happens to be at that memory location); in the second case, the `int` is initialized to 0.

But most importantly, these are two completely different beasts in respect to the first ones. You are not declaring an automatic variables of type `int`, but *pointers* to `int`, which point to two *dynamically allocated* `int`s.

The difference is deep: with `int i=0` the memory is managed automatically (it has *automatic storage duration*), and the variable is destroyed when it goes out of scope; with `new` you allocate memory from the freestore (the so-called heap), which doesn't have an automatic deallocation method - you have to free it explicitly (with `delete`, although in modern C++ smart pointers are normally used to automatically manage the lifetime of dynamic objects).

`new` is normally used exactly for the cases of when automatic storage duration isn't a good choice (e.g. you want those `int`s to outlive the current scope, or be shared between several objects or whatever) or when you are allocating stuff that is too big to stay in a local variable (in typical implementation local variables go on the stack, which is limited in size; still, for two `int`s that's not a valid concern).

For "regular", local `int` variables that have to "die" with the current scope `new` usually isn't a good idea.

Still, for more information about dynamic allocation you should check your C++ book.

Comment: If we're being pedantic, _it will have whatever value happens to be at that memory location_ isn't strictly correct; it can't be known what value uninitialised variables have since it's implementation-specific.

Answer (score -2):

`new` implies heap memory allocation (which can leak), so no, you don't want to be doing it all the time.

`int i=0;` and `int i(0);` are equivalent, but depending on the implementation the first may use an assignment operator while the second may be constructed with a value. This can let the compiler optimize for the target architecture. In the case of a class, the assignment method is probably slower since it will create a class (usually with default values) and then it will go through an assignment and wipe out all those default values it just spent time assigning.

Someone may chime in and reference the language spec for a more accurate answer.

Comment: This is incorrect.  In C++, `Foo f = 0;` calls the _constructor_ for `Foo`.  If the relevant constructor(s) are marked `explicit`, the code fails to compile.  Under no circumstances, regardless of the implementation, does it invoke the assignment operator for `Foo`.